# Highcharts Text Bubble

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an image like so: 
[image: Line Graph]

I'm using flags for the text bubbles like so:

```
{
   type: 'flags',
   y: yPosition,
   name: 'Flags on series',
   showInLegend: false,
   data: [{
     x: xPosition,
     title: '<span class="status-legend ' + $filter('status')(impactType) + '"></span>'+'<span style="font-size: 14px; font-family: \'MyriadPro-Regular\'; color: white">' + date + ': ' + title + '</span><br>' + text + '<br>' + impact + '<br>'
   }],
   shape: 'squarepin',
   style: {
     fontSize: '12px',
     fontWeight: 'normal',
     fontFamily: 'MyriadPro-Regular',
     textAlign: 'left',
     color: '#E7E7E7'
   },
   fillColor: 'rgba(151, 151, 151, 1)',
   color: 'rgba(151, 151, 151, 1)',
   useHTML: true,
   zIndex: zIndex,
   states: {
     hover: {
       enabled: false
     }
   }
 }
```

My problem is that the line goes all the way to the bottom, instead of stopping at the red circle. I can't think of a clever way to have the line stop.

Some things I've tried:

1. **Use Highstock's onSeries** - The issue here is the position of the bubble is now based on the yPosition vs the location of the circle. I've written logic to avoid placing two boxes on top of each other and this logic is far more difficult and strict if they all have different starting locations. This difficult is expounded by the flag's y value is a pixel value, not the yAxis's scale.
2. **Use Flag Spacing** - This only works on flags on the same value, flags to the left or right will be overlapped.
3. **Use a line graph that goes from the red dot to the text bubble** - The issue here is again, the red dot's position can be easily located since I know it's yAxis value, but the text bubble's position again is a pixel value, not on the same scale as the yAxis.

**I'm just looking for any way to show the text bubbles so they are not overlapping**. My best hope, I would guess, is there is some way I can use the yAxis's scale on the flags, or there is some other method I can place Text Bubbles which use the yAxis's scale.

Looking for any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `onSeries` to you flags, [See Here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/flag-series). You need to fill that in with the ID of the Series, otherwise if it is blank, it will draw to the X axis. [Also See](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.flags.onSeries)

```
{
   type: 'flags',
   y: yPosition,
   name: 'Flags on series',
   showInLegend: false,
   onSeries : '',
   data: [{
     x: xPosition,
     title: '<span class="status-legend ' + $filter('status')(impactType) + '"></span>'+'<span style="font-size: 14px; font-family: \'MyriadPro-Regular\'; color: white">' + date + ': ' + title + '</span><br>' + text + '<br>' + impact + '<br>'
   }],
   shape: 'squarepin',
   style: {
     fontSize: '12px',
     fontWeight: 'normal',
     fontFamily: 'MyriadPro-Regular',
     textAlign: 'left',
     color: '#E7E7E7'
   },
   fillColor: 'rgba(151, 151, 151, 1)',
   color: 'rgba(151, 151, 151, 1)',
   useHTML: true,
   zIndex: zIndex,
   states: {
     hover: {
       enabled: false
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this but the issue I've ran into is my boxes start to overlap on each other. For example, if I tell one to be 60px above another one, if it's marker is 60px lower they will be the same height and covering. Do you know how I can use onSeries but still have everything use the same starting position (ie, 0 for yPosition would make everything at the same height)

Comment: Can you post a photo of that behavior as well? It would be easier to visualize.

Comment: [Picture](http://i.imgur.com/hSGjnNf.png) I had to revert to an older version, but this gives an example of how there is overlap. Each one has a height of 100 pixels, but none of them are the same height since it is dependent on where the thing it is in reference to is located. This makes it very hard to space them out evenly.

Comment: add `y: yPosition,` to your data object as well.

Comment: Were you able to try setting y in flag's data object?